# Importing JSON file using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file that looks like

```
{[{ "EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" },{ "EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" }]}
```

I am trying to read it in C# and if I have 1 element in my JSON, it works fine. However if I have multiple elements, the code has this error

> Invalid property identifier character: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.

My code

```
var data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationModel>(data);
```

Model

```
public class VerificationModel
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string printDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your json looks like an array of things. Does that match your model? Please post your `VerificationModel` model.

Comment: It's invalid for JSON to have `{` immediately followed by `[`. Think about it; what does that specify? An object with an array inside it that's not a property?!? How?

Comment: As a C# developer it took me a long time to get json syntax down. Before I got good at it, if I had a json error, I would mock up a test object in C#, serialize it to a string, then see what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because your `json` is not valid. It should either be defined as an object with parameters:

```
{ "Key": Value }
```

where Value can be an single value, another object, or an array.

Or it should be defined as an array:

```
[ Value, Value2, Value3, ..., ValueN ]
```

The issue with your Json is that you are defining it as an object, but then where it is expecting a `Key` you just define an array without an `Key` at line 1, position 1.

position 0 being `{` and position 1 being `[`

I don't know what your verification model looks like, but lets assume it is something like:

```
public class VerificationModel {
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? PrintDate { get; set; }
}
```

then your Json should look like this:

```
[{ "EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" },{ "EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" }]
```

And your deserilization should look like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VerificationModel>>(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

TL/DR

Your json should start and end using just the array(square) brackets in which will be placed object that is going to be deserialized.

`[{VerificationModel1},{VerificationModel2}]`

Using your example it will be:

```
[
    { "EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" },
    {"EmployeeID": "123456", "statusCode": "100", "printDate": "01/01/2021" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. The text within the opening curly braces must consist of key-value pairs. Reformat it as follows, renaming "d" to whatever is appropriate for your top-level element:

```
{
   "d": [{
      "EmployeeID": "123456",
      "statusCode": "100",
      "printDate": "01/01/2021"
   },
      {
         "EmployeeID": "123456",
         "statusCode": "100",
         "printDate": "01/01/2021"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The `d` field isn't necessary. Just read the file into a list of objects